# Setting a nested object value

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var object = {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2",
    "subobject": {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": "value2",
        "subobject": {
            "property1": "value1",
            "property2": "value2",
            "subobject": {...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to set one of the nested subobject properties, but the nested level is dynamic.

How can I dynamically set one of these nested properties without doing something like this: `object.subobject.subobject = { ... }`?

**Edit:**
So to be more specific, I am trying to set one of the nested subobjects, but I won't know which one each time.

Comment: Define *dynamic*. As you seem to be on the right track.

Comment: You have following **object**, not JSON which would be quoted string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use recursion!

```
function setNest(obj, level, val){
    if(level > 0){
        setNest(obj.subobject, level-1, val);
    }
    else{
        obj.subobject = val;
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
setNest(object, 2, {a: 12});
```

Comment: Wow, where is my brain today.  I am not 100% sure why I didn't consider a recursive function... I was trying to do it in a loop.  Thanks for the extra pair of eyes!

Comment: You're welcome.  Recursion can be tricky, but it's perfect for situations like this :-)

Comment: I have tried to implement a solution that incorporates this, but it seems that this function is not updating the value of the original object. Any thoughts?

Comment: @KennyThompson: It seems to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/cYaML/1/  Object references in JavaScript are weird.  Maybe you're dealing with a copy and the the *original* original object?

Comment: After some digging, if appears that we are just altering the local variable obj and not the "object" variable (.. bad naming of the example i know.)

Comment: I pass the original variable when I call the function

Comment: @KennyThompson: References in JavaScript are weird.  I thought objects were always passed by reference.  Is there a case where that wouldn't happen?

Answer (score 7):

Using recursion - refactor (thanks Rocket Hazmat)

This function works for me!:

```
/**
 * @obj: the json object to change
 * @access: string dot separates route to value
 * @value: new valu
 */
function setValue(obj,access,value){
    if (typeof(access)=='string'){
        access = access.split('.');
    }
    if (access.length > 1){
        setValue(obj[access.shift()],access,value);
    }else{
        obj[access[0]] = value;
    }
}
```

Having an object:

```
var jsonObject = {
    'name' : 'pepe',
    'links' : 
        {
        'link1' : 'one',
        'link2' : 'two',
        'link3' : 
            {
            'link31' : '3url',
            'link32' : '3url',
            'link33' : '3url'
            }
        }
 }
```

We can change a value easy with:

```
 setValue(jsonObject,'links.link3.link32','new value!!!');
```

Thanks

Comment: There is a missing object initialisation. ```setValue(obj[access.shift()],access,value);``` should be ```setValue(obj[access.shift()] = {},access,value);```.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own Object methods; also I'm using underscore for brevity:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

// a fast get method for object, by specifying an address with depth
Object.prototype.pick = function(addr) {
    if (!_.isArray(addr)) return this[addr]; // if isn't array, just get normally
    var tmpo = this;
    while (i = addr.shift())
        tmpo = tmpo[i];
    return tmpo;
};
// a fast set method for object, put value at obj[addr]
Object.prototype.put = function(addr, val) {
    if (!_.isArray(addr)) this[addr] = val; // if isn't array, just set normally
    this.pick(_.initial(addr))[_.last(addr)] = val;
};
```

Sample usage:

```
var obj = { 
           'foo': {
                   'bar': 0 }}

obj.pick('foo'); // returns { bar: 0 }
obj.pick(['foo','bar']); // returns 0
obj.pick('foo.bar'.split('.')); // equivalent as above, returns 0
obj.put(['foo', 'bar'], -1) // obj becomes {'foo': {'bar': -1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn), like so:

```
var immutableJsObject = Immutable.fromJS({
  inputs: {
    firstDepthNumberOne: {
      secondDepth: 'secondDepthValue'
    },
    firstDepthNumberTwo: 'hello'
  }
});

var newImmutableJsObject = immutableJsObject.setIn('inputs.firstDepthNumberOne.secondDepth'.split('.'), 'newValue');

newImmutableJsObject.toJS();
```